# Does play have the concept of environments like Rails e.g. test,dev,prod? Config file questions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

Does play have the concept of environments build into the framework?

For instance in rails there are 3 sections for settings like `test, development and production`.

If yes, I want to have some branching in my code based on the environment, is this possible?

When I publish to production, can I still manually update my configuration file or does it get baked into the .jar file and I have to rebuild to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has, you should browse [BASIC documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Home), especially [additional confs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration) section

Comment: what's with the caps? :)  Looks like it has it but it isn't' baked into the framework like rails i.e. the files are in place when the project template is generated.  thanks!